# Roles.GetRolesForUser() & Roles.GetAllRoles() returns empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

web.config

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SqlRoleManager"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
         />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

in asp.net mvc 5, i'm trying to detect the role of the current user so i can redirect him to a page specific to it's role but

in my controller

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.GetUserName(), "superadmin")
```

or

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "superadmin")
```

the both are not true, i'm sure that i'm logged bec `User.Identity.GetUserName()` is displaying my login

Trying to debug, i found that `Roles.GetRolesForUser()` is empty, i've checked online resources but still no solution

Further debugging shows that `Roles.GetAllRoles()` is also empty, but my AspNetRoles table has 5 records.

I've looked at AspNetUserRoles and i found my current User id assigned to specific role id

and i've successfully run `aspnet_regsql.exe` to add all features but still cannot get the Roles

i think `aspnet_regsql.exe` is for web forms (i'm not sure)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone so can't double-check, but I'm sure IsUserInRole() will accept a single argument like IsUserInRole("superadmin") to check the current user in a session. I would remove the username part because you're checking the current user and not a different named user. It's quicker and will at least check and eliminate one part of the logic.

How are you seeding the roles?